# Remove all empty lists from a list of lists Ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

please help.
I am trying to write two non-recursive functions in OCaml (a list of lists contains elements that are lists themselves)

1. `clear l` which takes a list of lists as an argument and returns the list of lists without empty lists if there are any.
   Example:  `clear [[2];[];[];[3;4;6];[6;5];[]]` 
   will returns
   `[[2];[3;4;6];[6;5]]`
2. `sort_length l` that sorts the elements of this list `l` according to their length. E.g. `sort_length [[2];[];[3];[6;5]]` returns `[[];[2];[3];[6;5]]`

I am only allowed to use these predefined functions: List.filter, List.sort, List.hd, List.tl, List.length and no others.
Thanks

For the second function, I have tried this so far, but I used `map` which is not allowed

```
let rec insert cmp e = function
  | [] -> [e]
  | h :: t as l -> if cmp e h <= 0 then e :: l else h :: insert cmp e t
  
let rec sort cmp = function
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> insert cmp h (sort cmp t)

let sort_length l =
  let l = List.map (fun list -> List.length list, list) l in
  let l = sort (fun a b -> compare (fst a) (fst b)) l in
  List.map snd l;;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here: https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfilter, `List.filter` returns all the elements of the list that satisfy the given predicate. So you must write a predicate that describes a list that is not empty. Another way of saying that a list is not empty is to say that "its size is greater than zero". So it would be possible to formulate `clear` in this way:

```ml
let clear list = 
  let is_not_empty l = (List.length l) > 0 in
  List.filter is_not_empty list
```

> **Small edit**
>
> As mentioned by **Chris Dutton**, using `List.length` may be inefficient. Another approach would be to express `is_not_empty` in this way:
>
> ```ml
>  let is_not_empty = function 
>  | [] -> false 
>  | _  -> true
> ```
>
> This approach is "better" because it does not require going through the whole list to see if it is empty or not.

For the second point, the `List.sort` function takes a comparison function between two elements (`'a -> 'a -> int`), here the comparison must act on the size of the lists.

In other words, the size of the two lists observed must be compared. One way to do this would be to use `Int.compare` (https://ocaml.org/api/Int.html#VALcompare) on the size of the two observed lists. For example:

```ml
let sort_length list = 
  let compare_length a b = 
     let la = List.length a in 
     let lb = List.length b in 
     Int.compare la lb
   in 
   List.sort compare_length list
```

There are more concise ways of writing these two functions but these implementations should be fairly clear.

Comment: The first doesn't even require using `List.length`. You could simply use pattern matching to determine if the list is empty. This is definitely more efficient given large lists. Whether easier to read is a matter of taste. `let clear lst = List.filter (function [] -> false | _ -> true) lst`

Comment: You are right. I take "I am only allowed to use these predefined functions: List.filter, List.sort, List.hd, List.tl, List.length and no others." at the first degree. But I'll add an small edit.

Comment: If only `List.compare_length_with` were on the menu.